# Will a Windows (7,XP) computer go to sleep or standby, while copying a file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

Will a computer go to sleep or standby, while copying a file?

Same question for Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Because copying a file is a system activity and not user activity.

You can read everything in more details at [Windows 7 sleeping during operations](https://superuser.com/questions/48809/windows-7-sleeping-during-operations).